# gtsummary Wrong covariate level name

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to create Cox tables using gtsummary/tbl_uvregression. One of my covariates is a factor df$Nodes12 <- cut(df$Nodes12, breaks=c(0,11,200), include.lowest= T, labels=c("<12 LN","≥12 LN"), ordered=T)

When I use this code:

```
df %>%
  select(time, status, Age, ASA, Nodes12) %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
   y = Surv(time = time, event = status),
   method = coxph,
   exponentiate = TRUE,
   pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2),
 )
```

Unfortunately, I get "Nodes12.Q" and "Nodes12.L" as level names instead of "<12 LN" and "≥12 LN"

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI5cJ.jpg)

Any suggestions?

tried to add mutate(Nodes12 = factor(Nodes12, labels = c("Yes","No"))) but that didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, including both code and data that we can run on our machines. My guess is that you have an ordered factor, and this is the default contrast in that case

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg colud you please check my answer and give me feedback. Many thanks.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Great! Thank you very much! I'll try to provide reproducible code in the future!

Answer (score 1):

**Why this output:**

[image]

The output means that your predictor `LN12` is an "ordered factor".
R knows that the elements in your category are not only distinct, but also
have a natural order.

The `.L` (=linear) and `.Q` (=quadratic) comes from the intention of R to fit a series of polynomial functions or contrasts of your variable `LN12`. From [fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297771/interpretation-of-l-q-c-4-for-logistic-regression).

**Here is an example how you can tweak and play around:**

[Example data from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474960/multiple-univariate-cox-regression-with-tbl-uvregression-function-from-gtsumm)

data:

```
dataSOF <-
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
      age = c(62, 57, 67, 74, 71, 67, 46, 71, 53, 63),
      disease = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
      death = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
      censored_survival_days = c(60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60), 
      censored_survival_status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    ), 
    row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

**ORDERED FACTOR**

```
ord_dataSOF <- dataSOF %>% 
  mutate(age50 = cut(age, breaks=c(0,50,100), include.lowest=TRUE,
                     labels=c("< 50 years", ">= 50 years"), ordered = TRUE))


tbl_uvregression(
    ord_dataSOF,
    method=coxph,
    y = Surv(time = censored_survival_days, event = censored_survival_status),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    include = -ID)
  )
```

[image]

**FACTOR**

```
factor_dataSOF <- dataSOF %>% 
  mutate(age50 = ifelse(age <50, "age<50", "age>=50"),
         age50 = factor(age50)) 

tbl_uvregression(
    factor_dataSOF,
    method=coxph,
    y = Surv(time = censored_survival_days, event = censored_survival_status),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    include = -ID)
  )
```

[image]

@Daniel D. Sjoberg Why does this not work using `modify_table_body` from (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70887776/rename-levels-of-a-factor-in-tbl-regression]

```
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)
 
dataSOF %>% 
  mutate(age50 = cut(age, breaks=c(0,50,100), include.lowest=TRUE,
                     labels=c("< 50 years", ">= 50 years"), ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
tbl_uvregression(
    method=coxph,
    y = Surv(time = censored_survival_days, event = censored_survival_status),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    include = -ID,
    label = list(
      age50 ~ "50 years")
  ) %>% 
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>% 
      mutate(age50  = ifelse(age50 == "0", "<50 year",
                             ifelse(age50 =="1", ">= 50 years",age50)))
  )

#error:
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `age50 = ifelse(...)`.
Caused by error in `ifelse()`:
! object 'age50' not found
```

Comment: You'd want to use `label == '<50 years'`. The original column age50 doesn't exist in table_body